# Do browsers know domains that are supposed to be encrypted?

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle

Do browsers have a list with sites that are supposed to be encrypted?

Could a man in the middle attack be performed by presenting a user a http site instead of an https site? That way the server would not need to provide a certificate.

It wouldn't show up as a secure site in the browser but I think most people wouldn't notice it. And it wouldn't warn the user, because there are legitemate sites which don't use https.

Would such an attack be possible or does the browser notice that the site is supposed to use https but doesn't?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The short answer: **they know a very limited number**.

[HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) was introduced to provide better guarantees that a website is being served over HTTPS when specified by the operator.

This works well for **websites you have visited recently** as your browser will remember their HSTS policy and refuse a plaintext connection.

For example, if you visit your (previous visited from home) bank's website from an untrusted network that happens to have a man in the middle attempting to downgrade the connection to plain HTTP, your browser will refuse to connect because it remembers the website's security policy.

If you have not visited the site previously, the man in the middle needs to not only downgrade the connection security, but also remove the HSTS header (`Strict-Transport-Security`) from the response. This isn't difficult.

The problem you have identified is the major limitation: what happens if you are the victim of a downgrade attack during the first visit.

One solution browsers have implemented is to package a **"pre-loaded HSTS list"** of popular websites known to require HTTPS. Obviously this cannot be comprehensive and even with the list, attackers can still setup security downgrade proxies at slightly related DNS names.

You can submit a domain for inclusion in the HSTS Preload List at [hstspreload.org](https://hstspreload.org/).

Comment: https://hstspreload.org/?domain=google.com

Comment: This doesn't check if something is in the list, just whether it can be added. Here's how to query the list: https://play.golang.org/p/jc6AO1SpWWz (you'll need to run this locally, the Go playground doesn't do networking)

Comment: The entry is: `{Name:google.com Mode: IncludeSubDomains:true}`

Comment: @kelalaka is right.  google.com is not preloaded  you can go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and query domains and see that gmail.com and mail.google.com are preloaded while google.com is not.  The entry cited:  {Name:google.com Mode: IncludeSubDomains:true}  is for includesubdomains

Comment: Good point @mcgyver, it seems I spoke too soon. Then I have no clue why that is. Someone more familiar with HSTS might have the answer.

Comment: I would be interested in the answer as well.  I can't find an explanation for why it would be though I would guess that domain has to be available over http somewhere.

Comment: yandex.com, yahoo.com, amazon.com, cnn.com don't exits, either. The bing is there.

Comment: Has there ever been a proposal for an HSTS-equivalent DNS record? Then the browser could find out if https is required before issuing any HTTP request at all.

Comment: Ah, [this presentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/79/materials/slides-79-websec-0) talks about that.

Comment: Not much. You could use a mechanism similar to [DANE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities) which provides certificate fingerprints through DNSSEC (ie: HSTS policy in a record), but even DANE (or DNSSEC) hasn't been widely deployed.

Comment: @Marc I suspect the lack of Google and some other big sites in the central HSTS preload lists may be as insurance against particularly draconian TLS stripping transparent proxies that force all internal traffic to be unencrypted. If your site is HSTS tagged by a client (either due to them previously visiting or it being in the preload list), a user connecting behind such a proxy will not be able to use your site at all.

Comment: You could add to your answer, that there are top-level domains that use HSTS and thus enforce TLS for all domains, i.e., the `.dev` domain. Maybe there are more, I only know it for sure for the dev TLD.

Comment: I'm not sure it adds much, the mechanism is the same, just that it's a TLD in the list.

Comment: What if a website actually downgrades its security policy between visits?  Wouldn't that effectively lock your browser out of that website?

Comment: Yes. They would first need to remove the HSTS headers, then wait for the `max-age` duration before downgrading their security.

Answer (score 16):

Security researcher [Moxie Marlinspike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moxie_Marlinspike) demonstrated this type of attack in 2009, using a tool that he created called 'sslstrip'.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibF36Yyeehw (beginning at about 8:34).

To prevent this type of attack, we now have [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) (HSTS).  Sites can include an HSTS header in their response, to inform browsers to always connect to the site by HTTPS in the future.  Upon receiving the HSTS response header from the site, the browser adds the site to an 'HTTPS-only' list that it maintains, so that going forward, the browser will only connect to that site by HTTPS. So, with a site that has implemented HSTS, an sslstrip attack may succeed on the first connection to the site, but HSTS prevents an sslstrip attack on subsequent connections.

To prevent an sslstrip attack on the first connection to the site, the site operator can include the site on an [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/).  HSTS preload lists are shipped with some browsers (e.g. Chrome), so that the browser knows to connect to these sites by HTTPS-only, even before connecting for the first time.